# Explain Thisssssssssasssssssssss

Tags: hadith

جملة من الاعلام الذين ضعفو هذا الكذاب الوضاع قال عنه يحيى بن معين : ( أبو أويس وإبنه ضعيفان ) ( تهذيب الكمال 1/240 ، تهذيب التهذيب 1/197 ) ، وقال مرة : ( إبن أبي أويس وأبوه يسرقان الحديث ) ( تهذيب الكمال 1/240 ، الضعفاء والمتروكين 1/117 ، تهذيب التهذيب 1/197 ) ، وقال : ( مخلط يكذب ليس بشيء ) (تهذيب الكمال 1/240 ، تهذيب التهذيب 1/197 ) ، وقال : ( إسماعيل بن أبي أويس لا يساوي فلسين ) ( تهذيب التهذيب 1/198 ) . - وقال النسائي : ( ضعيف ) ( تهذيب الكمال 1/240 ، الضعفاء والمتروكين 1/117 ، سير أعلام النبلاء 9/120 ) ، وقال مرة : ( ليس بثقة ) ( تهذيب الكمال 1/240 ، تهذيب التهذيب 1/197 ، سير أعلام النبلاء 9/121 ) . وقال النضر بن سلمة المروزي : ( هو كذاب ) ( الضعفاء والمتروكين لابن الجوزي 1/117 ، تهذيب التهذيب 1/197 ) . - وقال الدار قطني : ( لا أختاره في الصحيح ) ( تهذيب التهذيب 1/198 ، سير أعلام النبلاء 9/121 . ( - وقال أبو القاسم اللالكائي اللالكائي : : ( بالغ النسائي في

الرابط القصير إلى هذا المقطع) Permalink http://hadithtransmitters.hawramani.com/?p=85467#503552 Ibn 'Adi al-Jurjāni (d. 976 CE) - al-Kamil fi du'afa' al-rijal ابن عدي الجرجاني - الكامل في ضعفاء الرجال إسماعيل بن أبي أويس. واسم أبي أويس عبد الله بن عبد الله بن أبي أويس بن أبي عامر الأصبحي، وهو ابن أخت مالك بن أنس، ومالك خاله من المدينة، يكنى أبا عبد الله. حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ أَبِي عِصْمَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ أَبِي يَحي، قَالَ: سَمِعْتُ يحيى بن معين يقول: ابن أبي أويس وأبوه يسرقان الحديث، وأبـ أويس عبد الله بن عبد الله. سمعت ابن حماد يقول: سمعتُ النضر بن سلمة المروزي يقول: ابن أبي أويس كذاب، كان يحدث عن مالك بمسائل عبد الله وهب. وقال النسائي: إسماعيل بن أبي أويس ضعيف.

Comment: The site's language is English: in other words any post posted here must necessarily be in English or it will be closed/deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This simply states that Abu Uwais and his son were not trustworthy as reporters.

This is hadith criticism [Jarh] over them.